# Where can I find the descriptions for AD&D magic items?

Tags: magic-items, adnd-2e

Where can I find the stat blocks and information for magical (or potentially even mundane) objects from AD&D?

I am currently planning a 5e campaign using the Planescape setting, and in reading through *Uncaged: Faces of Sigil*, I found that quite a few characters have magical items listed in their descriptions.

Unfortunately, on attempting to do some Googling, I've found zilch as far as any stats, nor have I been able to figure out what book(s) I should consult to find more information. (Unsurprisingly, all the search results are extremely 5e focused, with occasional bits of 3.5 thrown in.)

---

As a note, I am aware of the extreme differences in how the numbers work in AD&D vs 5e, but I want to get a feel for what these items were doing at the time, so that I can figure out what to sub out for these NPCs in my campaign.

Comment: I think I have the AD&D book somewhere. Let me see if I can scan and transcribe some of the magic items from them. Any specific magic items you were looking for?

Comment: @JakeFuller There's a whole slew of them, and I don't remember exactly which ones they were. But if you have the name of the book handy to drop as an answer, that'd be supremely helpful for me to look into for my research! I suspect I'll need to reference items a lot.

Comment: I have to find the book unfortunately, so it could take me a bit. In the meantime, check out the links I answered with

Comment: @JakeFuller: (Re: your last comment, which has been deleted:) [Don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/33569)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dragonsfoot.org has almost 400 aA D&D magic items listed [here](https://www.dragonsfoot.org/mi/viewtype.shtml), and I found [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwii8s3vutvwAhXGIDQIHe6LB5oQFjADegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkingdomofsunndi.hpage.com%2Fget_file.php%3Fid%3D32785344%26vnr%3D851853&usg=AOvVaw2X_DAK-snSy_M46cJU0u-u) pdf for a complete list of AD&D magic items (haven't had time to check it out much yet unfortunately)

Also, if you're willing to buy some books, the *Encyclopedia Magica* is a four volume set contains all of the official AD&D magic items.

Comment: The complete list of AD&D magic items is the proper source, I can spot-verify the text in the pdf with my copy of the book.

Answer (score 3):

They're in the AD&D (2e) *Dungeon Master Guide* (just like that's the book they're in for 5e).

If you don't still have a physical copy lying around like I do, an official PDF version is [available at Dungeon Masters Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17552/Dungeon-Master-Guide-Revised-2e) for about US$10.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.